# Help with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

In a game I'm developing I have a ball which is connected to a rope and it moves in a pendulum motion. 
At some point this ball should move down, taking into account it's current position and an angle.

I'm having some trouble calculating it's destination vector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by "destination vector".  A figure might help.  The velocity of a pendulum is always perpendicular to the rope, so you can interchange the coordinates of the vector that represents the rope, change the sign of one, and you have a vector along or opposed to the velocity.  So if the vector along the rope is $(4,7)$, the velocity is alog $(7,-4)$.  You still need to scale it.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! here is a figure https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/334x406q90/661/SEoEGE.jpg

Comment: I see the figure and the dot labeled destination, but don't know what to make of it.  Are you saying the rope lets go and the ball flies toward the destination?  That won't happen.  If the rope lets go, the ball initially continues straight in the direction it was going, then the path arcs due to gravity.

Comment: At the point when ball moves down all the physics simulations are stopped for both ball and rope. Ball and rope should move down together. sorry for the confusing explanation.

Comment: If the physics simulations are stopped, then you can just put them where you want.  If they are moving down, just add or subtract some value in the proper coordinate.  I think in gaming you increase $y$.  I think your problem is not mathematical, it is understanding what you want to do.  If you can clearly describe what you want to do, the math will follow.